# Why can't I move a mat-slide-toggle within the form tags?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have a working slide toggle that is working perfectly except when I want to change the location for the toggle on the view to next to the form it doesn't work.  Once I put it within the form tag the toggle will stop changing on click and will remain false.

I have looked at other examples but they are not using mat form field as is done in this code.  I need to put the toggle next to the submit button but the mat form field seems to make it not work.  Also I tried to add the same class to the form tag but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="container w-75 example-margin">
  <div class="row text-center mx-auto">
    <form class="form-inline row text-center mx-auto" [formGroup]="slgForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="mr-4">
          <input matInput formControlName="year" placeholder="Year">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="mr-4">
          <input matInput formControlName="quarter" placeholder="Quarter">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="mr-4">
          <input matInput formControlName="week" placeholder="Week">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="mr-4">
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment" formControlName="dept">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let department of departments" [value]="department">
              {{department}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="checked"
                        class="example-margin"
                        [color]="color"
                        (change)="changed()">
        Remove {{checked}}
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[(ngModel)]="checked"
```

When you put the slide toggle out the form, your model is not binding to the form.

Why do you want to put it outside the form?

Comment: Not sure, but I just was able to do it outside of the form.  I put it in the form and its working now

Comment: </mat-form-field>
          <mat-slide-toggle class="example-margin mr-4"
            [color]="color"
            formControlName="toggle"
            (change)="changed()">
            Remove {{slgForm.get('toggle').value}}
          </mat-slide-toggle>

Comment: Had to add it to the formController